# Parsing date object in Postman to be converted to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net, postman

I would like to know how I can parse a date in my JSON object that can be converted to DateTime in my WebApi controller.

```
myObject: {
              "key":"value",
               ...
              "DateOfBirth": "" // <-- What should I parse my date as here?
          }
```

FYI, I am using Postman to test my RESTful endpoints.

Comment: From the Newtonsoft Docs: `The default format used by Json.NET is the ISO 8601 standard: "2012-03-19T07:22Z".`

Comment: Thanks Adaam, I will try this.

Answer (score 9):

I am using the following Json Snippet to test our API.  If you want only Date, you can use Year-Month-Day format.

```
{       
    "messageId": "{{$guid}}",
    "identityToken": "{{identityToken}}",
    "UserLogin": "test_login",
    "StartDate" : "2017-08-01",
    "EndDate" : "2017-08-09"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As @adaam pointed to the doc in the comment, the correct format is `2016-06-03T10:34`. We use this to test our API endpoints and it works as expected.